# Store value of php array variable to javascript array variable

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps-api-3

i have some problem, how to store value of php array variable to javascript array variable because i want to manipulate data in javascript
here's my code

```
<?php  
$coor= array('-7.175993,112.650729|-7.17616,112.651139|-7.176591,112.650968|-7.176413,112.650552|-7.176104,112.650437','-7.176331,112.649924|-7.17632,112.650053|-7.176629,112.650048|-7.176629,112.649914');
?>
```

And i want to store all the values from $coor to var allcoor = new Array(), what i've been trying is use json_encode

```
<script>
var allcoor=new Array();
allcoor = "<?php foreach ($cobadeh as $t){echo json_encode($t);} ?>";
//for some example of manipulation array variable javascript
mySplitResult = allcoor[0].split("|");
...
</script>
```

What I want is manipulation of javascript array variable, and that code didn't work, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start out with a php array that mirrors the javascript array that you want.  Then output the results of json_encode on that array.

For this I am assuming you want an array of arrays.

```
<?php
$coorStr = "-7.175993,112.650729|-7.17616,112.651139|-7.176591,112.650968|-7.176413,112.650552|-7.176104,112.650437','-7.176331,112.649924|-7.17632,112.650053|-7.176629,112.650048|-7.176629,112.649914";
$coor= explode("|",$coorStr);
$coor = array_map(function($a) { return explode(",", $a); }, $coor);
?>
allcoor = <?php echo json_encode($cobadeh); ?>;
```

The first explode command splits the string into an array of elements containing each of the coordinate pairs.

The array_map call splits each of element in an array.

Finally the json_encode formats the data correctly for a javascript assignment.

Since the variable is a php array and you want it as a javascript array

Comment: it doesnt work. i have two element in variable '$cobadeh', and after i successing store data from '$cobadeh' to 'allcoor', i want to manipulation first element in 'allcoor', and i try 'mySplitResult = allcoor[0].split("|");' but didnt work, any suggestions?

Comment: @BryanAndiGerrardo Filled out the answer some more in hopes that it would produce the output you want.  If you need something different show a bit of how you want the json string to look.

Comment: sorry, my fault, i've been trying again, your suggestion was right, thank you masbroo

Answer (score 1):

first you create an array in the php side

```
$coor='-7.175993,112.650729|-7.17616,112.651139|-7.176591,112.650968|-7.176413,112.650552|-7.176104,112.650437','-7.176331,112.649924|-7.17632,112.650053|-7.176629,112.650048|-7.176629,112.649914';

$corar = explode("|", $coor);
```

and then in the javascript side you can do

```
var allcoor = <?php echo json_encode($corar); ?>;
```